# I want to invoke one durable function when new message received to service bus queue and need to pass same message to durable function

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, python-3.9, azure-durable-functions

I want to invoke one durable function when new message received to service bus queue and need to pass same message to durable function.

and the total procedure should be done in python stack

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you expect. StackOverflow is not a site where you can ask others to write code for you. Instead we expect you to write down what you have tried, including some code, and what your actual problem is. Than we are able to help you solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not asking other to write code. Just I'm asking to guide me, but now my task is already is completed. Thanks for your response